# Windows 10 sees Android folder with 5000+ files as empty

Tags: windows-7, android, sd-card, file-recovery

The SD card on my phone had a folder with about 5500 files in it. I could access it just fine on my phone, but whenever I connected it to my computer (Windows 10), the folder appeared empty. I accidentally moved that folder to my computer, and now what's left is an empty folder on my computer and nothing on my SD card. Considering the 'transfer' was instant I assume the files are still technically on my SD card.
Are those files technically deleted ? Do I need to run some recovery software or is there a simpler way to get them back ?

I've tried using different files explorer, both on Android and Windows, but they do not show anything different.

Comment: As a rule of thumb never move anything using the MTP protocol. There were and may be are bugs in the MTP protocol the end in data loss when moving files. Moving a folder means deleting it. Thus your files are now deleted. Not sure how the chances are for data recovery.

Comment: I tried a different recovery software and recovered most of it. It seems the files were technically transferred to the computer after all. What do you recommend for moving files from a phone to a computer ?

Comment: There are some unclear points about this question: How exactly did you access the SD card on your PC? Using your phone connected with a USB cable? Or using the SD card in a card reader? How did you “move” the folder? How exactly did you manage to recover the files afterwards? From where? SD card or the computer’s internal storage?

Comment: The SD card was mounted on my phone which was then connected to my computer through a USB cable. I right-cliked "moved" the folder onto my hard drive, which was for sure a bad idea, I could have just copied it and deleted it afterwards to be safe. I recovered the files through some deleted files recovery software (EaseUS Data Recovery to be specific), while scanning the folder on my computer in which I wanted to transfer the files. It seems that contrary to my original idea, the files were indeed transferred to my computer but then deleted.